# WordPress the_content()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to figure out why this function the_content() is showing 2 links at the bottom of any page I create from the dashboard. It also duplicates the title as you can see in  the image below. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: Booking Template
*/

//response generation function
$response = "";

//function to generate response
function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){

global $response;

if($type == "success") $response = "<div class='success'>{$message}</div>";
else $response = "<div class='error'>{$message}</div>";

 }

  //response messages
$not_human       = "Human verification incorrect.";
$missing_content = "Please supply all information.";
$email_invalid   = "Email Address Invalid.";
$message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
$message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";

//user posted variables
$name = $_POST['message_name'];
$email = $_POST['message_email'];
$message = $_POST['message_text'];
$human = $_POST['message_human'];

//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = "Someone sent a message from ".get_bloginfo('name');
$headers = 'From: '. $email . "rn" .
  'Reply-To: ' . $email . "rn";

if(!$human == 0){
if($human != 2) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
else {

  //validate email
  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
  else //email is valid
  {
    //validate presence of name and message
    if(empty($name) || empty($message)){
      my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
    }
    else //ready to go!
    {
      $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
      if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!
      else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
    }
  }
 }
}
else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error",                           $missing_content);  

 get_header(); ?>

 <div id="content" class="<?php echo implode( ' ', responsive_get_content_classes() ); ?  >">
```

```
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <header class="entry-header">
          <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </header>

        <div class="entry-content">
          <?php the_content(); ?>

           <?php echo $response; ?>
          <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
            <p><label for="name">Name: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>"></label></p>
            <p><label for="message_email">Email: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>"></label></p>
            <p><label for="message_text">Message: <span>*</span> <br><textarea type="text" name="message_text"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea></label></p>
            <p><label for="message_human">Human Verification: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" style="width: 60px;" name="message_human"> + 3 = 5</label></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
            <p><input type="submit"></p>
          </form>

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

      </article><!-- #post -->

  <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</div><!-- #content -->
```

[image: I'd only like to show one title and one content]

Comment: Can you please post page / template code?

Comment: Here is the entire code. My goal is to add a page template to an existing theme. It contains a form, basic fields for now.

Comment: Post your functions.php file, look for filters for the_content

Answer (score 0):

`the_content` is a filter, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content. So if i don't act as expected and don't act as default look up the filter in your functions.php. You will find functions.php in your theme folder.
Most likely your filtered function calls the `the_title()` filter again.

The link and URL are maybe the result of a mall formatted "read more" link. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More